# How to convince Devel::Trace to print the BEGIN-block statements?

Tags: perl

Have a simple script p.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our $x;
BEGIN {
    $x = 42;
}
print "$x\n";
```

When I run it as:

```
perl -d:Trace p.pl
```

prints:

```
>> p.pl:3: our $x;
>> p.pl:7: print "$x\n";
42
```

how to get printed the BEGIN block statements too, e.g. the `$x = 42;`?

Because my intention isn't clear, adding the clarification:

Looking for ANY way to print statements when the perl script runs (like Devel::Trace it does) but *including* the statements in the BEGIN block.

Comment: @toolic why wouldn't it? It certainly prints an `END` block. But probebly it's not completely loaded at the time the `BEGIN` is executed.

Comment: Yes. So, could be more precise. How get printed the BEGIN block statements (like with the -d:Trace) but in ANY other way? (e.g. by using the DB:: or such?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very possible. Set `$DB::single` in an early `BEGIN` block.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our $x;
BEGIN { $DB::single = 1 }

BEGIN {
    $x = 42;
}
print "$x\n";
```

`$DB::single` is a debugger variable used to determine whether the `DB::DB` function will be invoked at each line. In compilation phase it is usually false but you can set it in compilation phase in a `BEGIN` block.

This trick is also helpful to set a breakpoint inside a `BEGIN` block when you want to debug compile-time code in the standard debugger.

Comment: Thank you. One question. Where is this documented?

Comment: Funny how I read past this when researching my answer. Didn't occur to me to try it though. :)

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: This is just an attempt to explain the behaviour.*

---

Devel::Trace hooks up to the [Perl debugging API](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB.html) through the DB model. That is just code. [It installs a sub](https://metacpan.org/source/MJD/Devel-Trace-0.12/Trace.pm#L8) `DB::DB`.

The big question is, when is that executed. According to [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END), there are five block types that are executed at specific points during execution. One of them is `BEGIN`, which is the first.

Consider this program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our ($x, $y);

BEGIN { $x = '42' }
UNITCHECK { 'unitcheck' }
CHECK { 'check' }
INIT { 'init' }
END { 'end' }

print "$x\n";
```

This will output the following:

```
>> trace.pl:8: INIT { 'init' }
>> trace.pl:3: our ($x, $y);
>> trace.pl:11: print "$x\n";
42
>> trace.pl:9: END { 'end' }
```

So Devel::Trace *sees* the `INIT` block and the `END` block. But why the `INIT` block?

Above mentioned perlmod says:

> INIT blocks are run just before the Perl runtime begins execution, in "first in, first out" (FIFO) order.

Apparently at that phase, the `DB::DB` has already been installed. I could not find any documentation that says when a `sub` definition is run exactly. However, it seems it's after `BEGIN` and before `INIT`. Hence, it does not see whatever goes on in the `BEGIN`.

Adding a `BEGIN { $Devel::Trace::TRACE = 1 }` to the beginning of the file also does not help.

I rummaged around in documentation for perldebug and the likes, but could not find an explanation of this behaviour. My guess is that the debugger interface doesn't know about `BEGIN` at all. They are executed very early after all (consider e.g. `perl -c -E 'BEGIN{ say "foo" } say "bar"'` will print *foo*.)

Comment: For what it's worth anyway.

Comment: +1, thank you for the explanation. This is *first* time when i saw an answer like: "it is impossible". ;) Usually, for the "impossible" questions got answers, like: _it *is possible* but only by brutal hacking_ ... :) :D

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible. I just don't know how. :-P